# Splitting ArrayLists into Multiple ArrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, arraylist

I was wondering how I could split the following data into multiple lists. Here's my input (from a text file, sample recreated here):

```
aaaa bbbb cccc,ccc,cccc

aaaa-- bbbb

aaaa bbbb cccc-

aaaa bbbb cccc,ccc

aaaa-

aaaa bbbb ccc,cccc,cccc
```

Seperating each section of text is a blank space. The code I need to make should create three lists, composed of the a, b, and c groups of each entry from the text file with respect to each line, while ignoring any line with the "-". So, my 3 arrays should be filled as follows:

```
Array1: aaaa, aaaa, aaaa
Array2: bbbb, bbbb, bbbb
Array3: (cccc,ccc,cccc),(cccc,ccc),(ccc,cccc,cccc)
```

Parenthesis were added to show that the third Array should include all the listed c values
a,b, and c all contain strings imported from text files. Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SEED{

public static void main (String [] args){

    try{

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Curated.txt"));
        String temp;
        String dash = "-";
        int x = 0;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> syn = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();


        while((temp = in.readLine()) != null){

            if(!(temp.contains(dash))){

                list.add(temp);

                if(temp.contains(" ")){

                    String [] temp2 = temp.split(" ");
                    names.add(temp2[0]);
                    syn.add(temp2[1]);
                    id.add(temp2[2]);

                }else{

                    System.out.println(temp);

                }//Close if

                System.out.println(names.get(x));
                System.out.println(syn.get(x));
                System.out.println(id.get(x));

            x++;


            }//Close if


        }//Close while

    }catch (Exception e){

e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(99);

    }//Close try

}//Close main

}//Close class
```

But my output is always: nothing. How could I save these values to 3 separate Arrays or ArrayLists properly?

Comment: well, I'd iterate on all elements and I'd use a lot of if's and string's contains() to do that.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Santos, I was able to find the following error:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
 at SEED.main(SEED.java:39)

Comment: and I would not use a System.exit(99) in your exception handling either

Answer (score 1):

You're referencing **list.get(x)**, but your **x++** and your **list.add** won't be in synch if you read a line with no dash. So **(x)** won't be the correct reference.

Why are you doing:

```
String [] temp2 = list.get(x).split(" ");
```

Instead of:

```
String [] temp2 = temp.split(" ");
```

**EDIT**

Try:

```
if(!(temp.contains(dash))){

            list.add(temp);

            if(temp.contains(" ")){

                String [] temp2 = temp.split(" ");
                names.add(temp2[0]);
                syn.add(temp2[1]);
                id.add(temp2[2]);
            }else{

                System.out.println(temp);

            }//Close if

        }//Close if

for(int x = 0; x < names.size(); x++) {

            System.out.println(names.get(x));
            System.out.println(syn.get(x));
            System.out.println(id.get(x));
}
```

Comment: Oh, that would make it somewhat simpler. Honestly I was just thinking in terms of lists when I wrote the code. But isn't my **x++** outside of the if statement that checks for the dash, and therefore shouldn't it update regardless via the while loop?

Comment: if you read a line with a dash, you're not adding it to list but you're still incrementing x. So when you reference list.get(x), you'll get an indexoutofbounds exception

Comment: That makes sense, but when I tried moving the **x++** statement so that it was only incremented when a dash was not detected, the same error occurred. Sorry if these seem like stupid questions, it's been years since I touched CS and I'm a bit rusty

Comment: Ahh I just thought about doing that, I used the alternative for loop three different times for each of my arraylists and it ended up working. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably an exception is being thrown and your are ignoring it.

Change your catch to

```
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(99);

}//Close try
```

Comment: I got an indexoutofbound exception. But why though - aren't my 3 lists getting larger as I add in more values to each? The exception was thrown at Index 1, Size 1, on line 39 of the code